# Split string not Working

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist, split

I have an arrayList myfavourites in which there is only one element at index 0, it contains the following

```
->  ed sheeran . .  beyonce . .  katty perry . . .
```

I would like to split the this string to put it in another array which will contains only names for example

```
       for(int f =0; f < myFavourites.size();f++){

       String[] someArray = null;
       someArray[f] = myFavourites.get(f).split("\\.");

   }
```

So as when i loop through the array myfavourites i can get index[0] =ed sheeran, index[1]= beyonce etc..
I tried to run the code above + below it is not show anything , can some tell me what is not working with my code, thanks.

```
System.out.println(someArray[1]);
```

which sould be returning **beyonce**

Comment: you don't actually print the result, so what do you think it would be showing?

Comment: also: split returns an array of Strings, not one single String. This shouldn't compile: someArray[f] = myFavourites.get(f).split("\\.");

Comment: yes i did print it

Comment: Not in the code you posted. Use [edit] option and post proper [mcve].

Comment: @Mattieu: not in the code you've shown. And, again: split("").. returns an array of Strings, you are trying to assign the result of split to a single String. The code you have shown will not work, please, post your actual code

Comment: This code won't even compile. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Stultuske it is a long piece of code, you would get confused believe me, the code what i've posted is the logic that i'm trying to implement

Comment: sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: "it is a long piece of code, you would get confused believe me" that is precisely why we are asking you to post *minimal* (without any unrelated/unnecessary things) but still *complete* (so we could copy-paste and compile/run it without modifications) example which allows us to *reproduce your problem*. If you expect others to spend their time on helping you be ready to spend your own time into making helping you as easy as possible.

Comment: no matter how long the code is, we just need to see the unit (most likely, method) you are trying to execute. The code you've posted so far will not compile, so we know it is not your actual code.

Comment: okay guys as requested here is the "Long piece of code"

Comment: have you been able to compile it ?

Comment: @MattieuKevin are you asking us whether you were able to compile it? no, of course we can't, you just posted a snippet. If we would try to compile it, there would be several variable declarations missing. Better question: seeing as it's clear that the question you asked originally has nothing at all to do with this code: what is it you want it to do, and what doesn't it do? have you debugged to verify the Strings contain the value you assume they do?

Comment: Sorry but it seems you are misunderstanding purpose of this site. We are here to build repository of programming problems/questions for future viewers (including us), not to help asker (that comes as a bonus). That is why we *require* from question to actually have code which at least allows to reproduce the problem. It is *your* task to ensure it. If you can't spend your time into creating [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) then I doubt many people will be willing to spend their time on your question. Anyway good luck.

Comment: okay lets forget what happened, so you were saying that split will return an array is that true ?

Comment: and what do you think, will split("\\.")  remove all the characters/ special symbols from my string ?

Comment: Yes, as stated in docmumentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String- where we see method is declared as `public String[] split​(String regex)` so return type is `String[]`. If you have string like `"a.b.c"` then `"a.b.c".split("\\.")` will produce array `["a", "b", "c"]`. If you are receiving something else then you are splitting different string than you assumed.

Comment: @Pshemo if i declare an array somearray , will someArray[] = order.get(f).split("\\.");  transfer the value to somearray

Comment: `someArray[] = order.get(f).split("\\.");` doesn't compile. You would need to add `String` at start to get something like `String someArray[] = ...`. Anyway I am not sure what you mean by "transfer the value to somearray".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split("\\.")`

works only if the string like this

`ed sheeran.beyonce.katty perry`

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` find all names:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "->  ed sheeran . .  beyonce . .  katty perry . . .  ";
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s?\\w+");
Matcher m = reg.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    names.add(m.group());
}
String[] someArray = names.toArray(new String[]{});
```

update:

If there are names like `A B C` or `A   B   C` or `A-B C`, this one is better:

```
Pattern.compile("\\w[ \\w\\-]*\\w");
```

Comment: @Mattieu Kevin Is there any name like `Daniel Day-Lewis`? If there is, you get more work to do...

Comment: `\\w+\\s?\\w+` looks like candidate for [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Possibly safer option would be `\\w+(\\s+\\w+)?`